# Custom Listbox Items not stretching

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-8

How would I make mainGrid horizontally stretch to the size of the listbox? I've got the listbox set to stretch and auto width and mainGrid set to stretch and auto but its not stretching to the size of the listbox.

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="AccountItem">
                <Grid Name="mainGrid" ShowGridLines="True">
                    <Grid.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFF3"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="DarkGray" Offset="0.672"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Grid.Background>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0" >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="accountName" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="White"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="accountType" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Type}" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Balance:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="White"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="accountBalance" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Balance}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="White" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="2" >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Available Balance:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="White"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="accountAvailableBalance" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding AvailableBalance}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="White" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="/Assets/background.png"/>
        </Grid.Background>


        <ListBox x:Name="accountsList" Margin="20,136,20,0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AccountItem}"  />

    </Grid>
```

Comment: " but I'm having trouble getting the data to display" - that's not a real question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set HorizontalContentAlignment to Strecth:

```
<ListBox x:Name="accountsList" Margin="20,136,20,0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AccountItem}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```